# Can I use an @tag in the Facebook REST API?

Tags: facebook, rest

I want to post to my newsfeed via the old REST API. If I use OpenGraph I can include in the content @1234567.. tags to tag other people in a post. Is that possible in the REST API?

EDIT: I added a 50 point bounty on a similar question [Is there a way to insert an @mention into a Facebook status update posted with pyfacebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787413/is-there-a-way-to-insert-an-mention-into-a-facebook-status-update-posted-with-py)

Comment: I understand this is called a Mention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not in the external APIs at the moment.